# Unable to get folder by id when using Boxr JWT get_user_token- Box API

Tags: ruby, jwt, box-api, box

I'm unable to a folder by providing an id to that folder using [Boxr](https://github.com/cburnette/boxr) gem. Previously I didn't has the `enterprise` settings as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652029/unable-to-get-folder-by-id-using-boxr-gem-ruby-sdk-for-box-api) which I have now fixed. I'm creating a token using JWT authentication `get_user_token` method the following way.

```
token = Boxr::get_user_token("38521XXXX", private_key: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'), private_key_password: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD'), public_key_id: ENV.fetch('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID'), client_id: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_ID'), client_secret: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_SECRET'))
```

I then pass this this token when creating a client.

```
client = Boxr::Client.new(token)
```

when I check the current user on client this is what I get:

```
client.current_user
=> {"type"=>"user",
 "id"=>"60853XXXX",
 "name"=>"OnlineAppsPoC",
 "login"=>"AutomationUser_629741_06JgxiPtPj@boxdevedition.com",
 "created_at"=>"2018-10-04T08:41:32-07:00",
 "modified_at"=>"2018-10-04T08:41:50-07:00",
 "language"=>"en",
 "timezone"=>"America/Los_Angeles",
 "space_amount"=>10737418240,
 "space_used"=>0,
 "max_upload_size"=>2147483648,
 "status"=>"active",
 "job_title"=>"",
 "phone"=>"",
 "address"=>"",
 "avatar_url"=>"https://app.box.com/api/avatar/large/6085300897"}
```

When I run `client.methods` I see there is `folder_from_id` however when I call that method I get the following error:

```
pry(#<FormsController>)> client.folder_from_id("123456", fields: [])
Boxr::BoxrError: 404: Not Found
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/boxr-1.4.0/lib/boxr/client.rb:239:in `check_response_status'
```

I have the following settings:
[image]

[image]

I also authorize the application. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 token = Boxr::get_user_token(user_id,
                        private_key: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
                        private_key_password: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD'),
                        public_key_id: ENV.fetch('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID'),
                        client_id: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_ID'),
                        client_secret: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_SECRET'))

client = Boxr::Client.new(token.access_token)
folder = client.folder_from_id(folder_id)
client.upload_file(file_path, folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using C# and BOXJWT.

You just need to have a boxManager set up and will get you with anything you need, say BoxFile, Folder etc.

If you have the folderID, well & good, but if you need to retrieve, this can be done as shown below:

```
string inputFolderId = _boxManager.GetFolder(RootFolderID).Folders.Where(i => i.Name == boxFolder).FirstOrDefault().Id;  //Retrieves FolderId
Folder inputFolder = _boxManager.GetFolder(inputFolderId);
```